# Laravel Required Field on Model Update

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

I have a Users system which allows account creation, login and logout procedures.

I'm currently working on an Edit Profile, which allows editing of the full name, username etc.
For this procedure, I would like the password to be not required, however, it needs to be required for the create and login procedures.

Is there a way to support this in Laravel?

I thought about detecting the presence of an Input::get('password') and if not, passing through the original password, however, this would re-hash

So, to summarise, I would like the password field to be required on create, but not on update procedures. Alternatively, if there's another way to achieve the same end, then I'm open to it.

For reference, I'm using [JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation) which handles the validation within the save procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you cannot do this using this package. However you can create such functionality manually, for example creating 2 methods that chooses required fields for validation, a piece of `User` class:

```
protected static $rules
    = [
        'name'            => 'required|min:3|max:60',          
        'password'        => [
            'required',
            'min:10'
        ],

    ];


public static function validateRegistration($data, $translation)
{
    return self::validate($data, $translation);
}

public static function validateUpdate($data, $translation)
{

    $rules = self::$rules;
    if (trim($data['password']) == '') {
        unset($rules['password']); // unsetting unwanted password rule
    }
    return self::validate($data, $translation, $rules);
}

public static function validate($data, $translation, $rules = null) 
{
    if (is_null($rules)) {
        $rules = self::$rules;
    }

    $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $translation);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        self::$errors = $v->messages()->toArray();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```